# Represent entryset of Map as type T

Tags: java

I need to represent each entry of a Map as type T and I don't know how to do that.

Here is the definition of entryset:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

so I need something like this:

```
Map<?,?> -> Set<T>
```

This will compile:

```
  public static <T, E> void Each(Map i, IEacher<T, E> m, Asyncc.IEachCallback<E> f) {
    NeoEach.Each(Integer.MAX_VALUE, i.<T>entrySet(), m, f);
  }
```

but I get a warning:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.Set' to 'java.lang.Iterable'.
>   Reason: 'i' has raw type, so result of entrySet is erased

but what's weird is that this won't compile:

```
  public static <T, E> void Each(Map<Object,Object> i, IEacher<T, E> m, Asyncc.IEachCallback<E> f) {
    NeoEach.Each(Integer.MAX_VALUE, i.<T>entrySet(), m, f);
  }
```

using `Map i` compiles, but `Map<Object,Object> i` won't it says:

*expected*:

```
i:java.lang.Iterable<T>
```

*actual*:

```
i.<T>entrySet()  (java...java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>>)
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you don't want to use `values()`?

Comment: Also, what's with the C# naming style?

Comment: I need to use entryset because I need key-value pairs not just the value.  For static variables sometimes I use capitals, I might change it, besides the point here.

Comment: Then you'll need some sort of transformation function.

Comment: @AlexanderMills *"I might change it"*? Well, you should definitely follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variable names *always* start with lowercase.

Comment: @MCEmperor instead of variable I think to be more precise you mean method names. According to the Java Naming Conventions local variables are distinct from method/field names.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Variable names (both local variables and instance variables) are written in camelCase, as well as method names.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NeoEach.Each` method accepts `Iterable<T>` but you are trying to force it to consume entry set of `Map<Object,T>`. This seems to me somewhat ambiguous. What should the method do with `Map.Entry` better than with `T` itself? If you utilize map key in `Each` method, pass entry set there instead of `Iterable` or pass `Iterable` of entries:

```
static <T, E> void Each(int limit, Iterable<Map.Entry<Object,T>> i, Asyncc.IEacher<T, E> m, Asyncc.IEachCallback<E> f) {
```

In extreme case, some reflection or proxy-based hacks could probably be done to fake `Map.Entry` to look like `T` but I believe that's not what both you and me actually want.

EDIT:
And what compiles to you does not mean it will run. Declaring raw `Map` just masks the problem, doesn't solve it. The attempt of treating rawtype `Map.Entry` as value type will fail on `ClassCastException` sometimes in the future.

Comment: upvoted, I updated the question to make it a little simpler to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Java Streams API to transform each Entry to T, but you must define how you would do that. You could then pass a transformation function to do the transformation to `T`.

```
public static <K, V, T> Set<T> transform(Map<K, V> map, Function<Map.Entry<K, V>, T> transformationFunction) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(transformationFunction)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

---

The reason why you cannot use `Map<Object, Object>` is that **[generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745301#2745301)**.

Comment: map.entrySet() should return Set<T>

Comment: @AlexanderMills "`map.entrySet()` should return `Set<T>`"? That can't be done, since the `Map` interface requires the `entrySet` method to return an `Entry<K, V>`; this cannot be magically changed to `Set<T>` ... or you need to implement your own map, adding a method which returns such a set.